# I am having trouble with this String Parser, how can I approach it?

Tags: java, string, parsing, java.util.scanner, indexof

1. Create a String variable and assign your full name to the variable.
2. Using the String's substring method print out your first name, middle name, and last name on three separate lines.
3. Modify your program so that it creates a "Scanner" object to allow the user to type in any three names and store it in the String variable.
4. Modify your program so that it will print out the three names on separate lines no matter what three names the user enters (Hint: use the String's indexof method).

So for this problem, I am doing it in Java. Here is what I have so far. Thank you!

```
package stringparser;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringParser
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        String Name = "Billy Bob Joe";
        String first = Name.substring(0,5);
        String middle = Name.substring(6,12);
        String last = Name.substring(13,16);

        System.out.println("First name: " + first);
        System.out.println("Middle name: " + middle);
        System.out.println("Last name: " + last);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type any 3 names: ");

        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String a = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Second name: ");
        String b = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Third name: ");
        String c = in.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework...

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: *"(hint: use the String's `indexOf` method)."* <- Seems pretty obvious to me

Comment: `"Can you solve this String parser"` -- Can you not dump your homework here without asking a ***specific*** question?

Comment: I am new to coding, and would greatly appreciate help. It comes easy to you, because you have many years of experience. I have only a few. Thank you.   @MadProgrammer also I don't the indexOf method. I have spent 4 hours on this problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I altered the question

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you tell me what is wrong with my code, and what I need. Thank you!

Comment: I'd start with having a look at [`String@indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and maybe [the Strings trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: Doing that right now! @MadProgrammer I made a minor adjustment.  and added public StringParser(){}

Comment: What if your teacher only has 2 names? LOL

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I interpret this question.

1. Use Scanner 3 times
2. Use indexOf to find the nearest space character of the one console input.

In all, I find it painfully inefficient to use `String.indexOf`

Quickest way, but not necessarily the best way.

```
public StringParser () {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(name.replace(" ", "\n")); // replacing all spaces with new line characters
}
```

Comment: If I go the route of making 3 Scanners, I would need 2 classes right? @John Giotta

Comment: No, not with the given example you provided. Is it required you use `indexOf`?

Comment: Well, I just have to get the same output. When my teacher runs the program, he will be altering the codes of the strings, to try to 'break' it. If he can't break it, I ace it. I just have to do the steps asked.  Is the scanner 3 times easier to do?

Comment: @MaxFritzhand Easy, yes and no, what your teacher is asking for, no

Comment: No, `Scanner` 3 times is repetitive for the user. Personally, I would use a `String[]` using `String.split()` to create the 3 names then loop for output. I believe your exercise is in String manipulation though.

Comment: Sorry John, but I am new to Java and coding. So this stuff is like way over my head.

Comment: for step 1.) would I do String name = "First Middle Name"; or                  String name = new ("First Middle Last");

Comment: I made some changes in the code, can you take a look?

Comment: You shouldn't have those double quotes around your `println`.  `System.out.println(Name.substring(13,16));` Your example source is a bit rough.

Comment: Hey, I think I almost solved it. I am on step 3.), if you can, can you do these quick last parts, that I have no idea what to do. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

This program will split the string with space and print all of them as result. You can edit the for loop condition as per your need. Hope it helps :)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = in.nextLine();
    String[] names = str.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
         System.out.println(names[i]);
    }
}
```